# How to produce a result with row and column headers and counts in the middle? (group by 2 fields)

Tags: mysql

Given a query like

```
 SELECT x,y,count(*) FROM t GROUP BY x,y
```

I want to reformat the data to look like:

```
   null   y1    y2    y3
     x1    1  null    14
     x2    3     4  null
     x3    2     1     5
```

Is this possible?

Or even if we can omit the first row...as long as I can determine what the colum headers are supposed to be (perhaps with a 2nd query)

(null or 0 for missing count sis fine, swapping row headers/colum headers is fine, top left value can be anything)

Comment: What does null mean in this context. If both `x1` and `y2` exist and you're counting the instances when they (don't in this case) exist then the answer will always be 0. You can hack it by using `nullif` on 0s but it's not "pretty".

Comment: @Ben: I imagine "null" would be when there is no record [x1,y2]. It wouldn't appear in the original result set, so it wouldn't even produce a count for it. "0" is actually preferable, but like you said, it's trivial to swap one for the other.

Comment: If amount of columns is not a fixed value - then it is impossible

Comment: @zerkms: Correct. Neither `x` nor `y` is fixed. Make your comment an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If amount of columns is not a fixed value - then it is impossible