# How can I transform this multi-dimensional array into an array with row and column headers?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array, transform

How can I transform an array like

```
array(
    0 => array(
        'x' => 'x1',
        'y' => 'y1',
        'count' => 2,
    ),
    1 => array(
        'x' => 'x3',
        'y' => 'y1',
        'count' => 3,
    ),
    2 => array(
        'x' => 'x3',
        'y' => 'y2',
        'count' => 4,
    ),
    3 => array(
        'x' => 'x1',
        'y' => 'y2',
        'count' => 6,
    ),
    4 => array(
        'x' => 'x2',
        'y' => 'y3',
        'count' => 7,
    ),
    5 => array(
        'x' => 'x2',
        'y' => 'y2',
        'count' => 1,
    ),
)
```

(which is the result of an SQL query)

into a header array:

```
    array('x','y1','y2','y3')
```

and value array:

```
array(
    0 => array('x1',2,6,null),
    1 => array('x2',null,1,7),
    2 => array('x3',3,4,null),
)
```

I'm trying take the [result set from a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674404/how-to-produce-a-result-with-row-and-column-headers-and-counts-in-the-middle-g) and turn it into a grid/table.

(err...sorry, I didn't use the exact same example set as from the other question)

I'm having trouble with coming up with a nice, efficient way of doing this.

---

The header array should just be the string "x" followed by all the distinct values for 'y'. For consistency, we can sort them alphabetically.

The last array should have 1 row for every distinct value of 'x' (which makes up the index 0) and the following indexes are taken from the corresponding 'count' for the respective x/y values from the first array (the 'y' value is given by the same index in the 'header' array). Missing values can be `null` or `0`.

Comment: Can you explain how the two arrays are constructed?

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa: The first one is the result of an SQL query (as hinted from the link)... the second I guess I can explain better in the question.

Comment: Where do the `null` value come from? Those are not part of the original array or am I missing something?

Comment: @hakre: Exactly. They're missing, so I made them null. 0 would work too.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you consider this nice, but it should be effecient.  Also, you could remove the `ksort`s for even better effeciency, if you only plan to `for` over the data... if you want `foreach` you'll need to keep them in.

```
$header = array('x');
$body = array();
$row_len = 0;

foreach ($input as $cell) {
    $x = (int) substr($cell['x'], 1);
    $y = (int) substr($cell['y'], 1);
    $row_len = max($row_len, $y);   // use for null-padding rows later

    $header[$y] = $cell['y']; 

    // Populate body
    $row =& $body[$x - 1];
    $row[0] = $cell['x'];
    $row[$y] = $cell['count'];
}

// Fill missing nulls
foreach ($body as &$row) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $row_len; $i++) {
        if (!isset($row[$i])) {
            $row[$i] = null;
        }
    }

    // Sort rows by key (since we've treated this as assoc-array)
    ksort($row);
}

// Once again, assoc arrays, you'll need to ksort
ksort($header);
ksort($body);
```

The first foreach is where the critical bit is.. the rest is to normalize your resulting array.